# Disable autohide for Gnome 3's bottom bar

Tags: linux, gnome3, gnome-shell

I like to work with maximized shell windows, and very often notifications I care little about appear at the bottom of the screen, right on top of my command line that I'm writing.

It would be much easier to ignore them if the notification bar was always visible. Is it possible to disable autohiding?